# The Cardinality of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

about the cardinality of these sets?

(a) $(A \cup B)$

(b) $(A \cap B)$

(c) $A  \times  B$.

(d) $A \smallsetminus B$.

(e) $P(A \cup B)$

I know if I want to find the union I use Cardinal Number formula:

$$n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cap B)$$

and for intersection 
$n(A\cap B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cup B)$

but I don't have all information only $A$ and $B$ . how to get cardinality in this way ?

Comment: "if not, explain why not; in that case, what can be said about the cardinality of these sets?" You can not find $|A\cup B|$ when only given $|A|$ and $|B|$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two scenarios:

- $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$
- $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

It should be clear that you get different answers for the cardinalities for each except for the cartesian product where you do get the same answer for each.  You are however able to find *bounds* for the cardinalities of each expression.  You should be able to argue, using exactly the inclusion-exclusion principle that you mention in your post ($|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$) that the various cardinalities are either minimized or maximized when there is as much overlap as possible or no overlap at all.

Comment: Would you please explain more? So I need to argue can't get the cardinality for all the them?

Comment: @Jared If we were to suppose that $|A\cup B|$ is possible to determine from the information $|A|$ and $|B|$ alone, then it would have been the case that regardless what we let $A$ or $B$ actually equal that $|A\cup B|$ would have been the same.  Since we have two examples here and in each of those examples $|A\cup B|$ is equal to something *different* and *not the same*, that directly implies that $|A|$ and $|B|$ alone are *not* enough information to uniquely determine $|A\cup B|$.  No further argument or proof is necessary.

Comment: @Jared As alluded to above, we *can* however find *bounds* for the sizes of the various sets.  For example $\max(|A|,|B|)\leq |A\cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B| \leq |A|+|B|$ so we learn that $7\leq |A\cup B|\leq 12$.  Further, the examples I outline above actually achieve those bounds so we know the bounds are strict.  You can come up with similar bounds for the other expressions, and you can argue as alluded to earlier that the examples where $|A\cap B|$ is either minimized or maximized achieve the extremes of the bounds.

Comment: Thanks , but for A×B and A- B Difference that can be determine?

Comment: @Jared $|A\times B|= |A|\times |B|$ in every case.  $|A\setminus B|$ however depends on how much overlap there is, again shown by the examples I provided above.  Note that $|A|=|A\cap B|+|A\setminus B|$

Comment: |a| - |b|  is there any specific rule for this to prove can'r get cardinality ?

Comment: @Jared I will say it again... this time in more explicit form.  $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and so if you were to look at my first example you have $|A\setminus B|= 5$.  On the other hand $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}=\emptyset$ so in my second example above you have $|A\setminus B|=0$.  By the fact that we have two different examples, each leading to different values of $|A\setminus B|$ you have as before that $|A|$ and $|B|$ are not enough to uniquely determine $|A\setminus B|$

Comment: @Jared *if* you have that $B\subseteq A$ then you have $|A\setminus B|=|A|-|B|$, however as directly evidenced by my examples above and in my previous comment if you do not know how much overlap $A$ and $B$ have there is not enough information to find an exact value for $|A\setminus B|$.  You do however have that $|A\setminus B|\leq |A|$ and $|A\setminus B|\geq \max(|A|-|B|,0)$